# How to add a dummy SOAPHandler for {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, soap, jax-ws

I am calling a SOAP service that uses WS-Security from JAVA using jax-ws. 
The problem is that the response contains some mustUnderstand headers and I get an *Element not understood SoapFaultException*.

The response header looks like this:

```
 <s:Header>
  <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
     <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
        <u:Created>2011-12-19T15:38:49.023Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2011-12-19T15:43:49.023Z</u:Expires>
     </u:Timestamp>
  </o:Security>
```

Could I add a dummy SOAPHandler for that header? or maybe modify it to mustUnderstand="0"? and how?

Answer (score 0):

Missed to override the getHeaders() method in the handler.Override getHeaders() method

```
@Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        final QName securityHeader = new QName(
            "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd",
            "Security",
            "wsse");

        final HashSet headers = new HashSet();
        headers.add(securityHeader);

        // notify the runtime that this is handled
        return headers;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share complete source code and where to configure this file ?